# how to convert string constant to preprocessing token in C

Tags: c++, c, macros

I want to convert string constant to preprocessing token  using macro.
Example:

```
    // get the first character of marco argument to postfix of new data type.
    #define TYPE(typename) Prefix ## typename #typename[0]
    void main()
    {
        TYPE(int) a, b, c; // Prefixinti a, b, c;
        TYPE(float) x, y, z; // Prefixfloatf x, y, z;
        a = 3;
    }
```

is it possible in C/C++?
p/s: sorry for my poor English. 
**edited**

Comment: You can't unstringize, only stringize.

Comment: But that should be all you need as long as your constant doesn't contain commas.

Comment: Tried very hard, but can't resist anymore: **why do this?**

Comment: I want to create user-defined data types using X macros. Example: In OpenGL. GLPoint3i, GLPoint3f : get the first character in data type (int ,float) to the postfix for my data types.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define TYPE(first_letter, rest) Prefix ## first_letter ## rest ## first_letter

typedef int TYPE(i,nt);
typedef float TYPE(f,loat);

int main(void)
{
  TYPE(i,nt) a, b, c; // Prefixinti a, b, c;
  TYPE(f,loat) x, y, z; // Prefixfloatf x, y, z;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a better solution? I want `TYPE(int) a, b, c;// Prefixiniti a, b, c;`

Comment: No, I don't know of another solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should alway remeber what the preprocessor does, it modifies your source code before the compiler even sees it.

This does compile( I removed the quotes around int) , but is not so usefull:

```
#define TYPE(typename) typename

void main()
{
    TYPE(int) a, b, c;
    a = 3;
}
```

What you are doing results in the following code sent to the compiler:

```
TYPE("int") a, b, c;
```

results in"

```
"int" a, b, c;
```

where a string constant is followed by a couple of undeclared identifiers, which result in a syntax error

Comment: I want to create user-defined data types using X macros. Example: In OpenGL. GLPoint3i, GLPoint3f : get the first character in data type (int ,float) to the postfix for my data types.

Comment: I think the openGL variables are created using typedef. have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro here you can see how to use X macro,

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, even with templates in C++. By the way, avoid using `typename` in C-code as it's a keyword in C++ so your C code would be difficult to port.

Also `void main()` is not strictly portable; use `int main()` instead.

Comment: `typename` makes no difference since the preprocessor runs before the compiler.

Comment: True but still naughty don't you think?